# how to view the inititator tab in the safari

Tags: safari

I am running my web app in safari I see a strange request to the URL
which is not seen in the Chrome.

themes/analytics/assets/fonts/PublicSans-Light.ttf

and I don't remember making such a request in the code.

in chrome, there is an `initiator` which tells who sends the request.
but in safari, the `initiator` tab is missing.

is there any way to see the request origin?